# ListItem Fill List And Overflow

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to have a `ListItem` that vertically fills the list completely, and sometimes overflows it.

That means I need access to the height of the empty space in the list. It would be the `minHeight`, and sometimes I would add some extra height to it. How do I have access to that?

I tried `display=flex` and `flexDirection=column` on the `List` and then `flexGrow: 1` on the `ListItem` and it did fill the empty space of the list, but never overflowed as I wanted.

Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe set  height:auto;max-height :100%;overflow: scroll;  will help you

Answer (score 0):

I think you can handle this issue in pure CSS. You should add these styles to your list element:

```
height: auto;
overflow-y: auto;
```

then when your list fills, it scrolls automatically